# Lookup with partial match of strings

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tables:

[image]

[image]

I want to identify from which group each person in TABLE 2 is, in a way it looks like this:

[image]

[Sample data here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RsbhcG4S2ZGd77ZSynPrWaNHdBArkSELKj51j7I-21o/edit#gid=0)

Tried using lookup but didn't find my way there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
={
  "Solution";
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    IF(
      D4:D = "";
        "";
        VLOOKUP(
          "*" & TRIM(D4:D) & "*";
          TRIM(A5:A);
          1;
          0
        )
     )
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your answer! I fixed the typo (you were right). It works for the sample however when I put that to run in a long column, in the end where there is no extra data it keeps repeating the first item "Rosangela Lima, Ana Carolina Chagas,...". Would there be a way to make it blank?

Comment: @abutremutante you are welcome! I fixed the solution to handle empty key cells from Table 2.